# Include Google Analytics to TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I've added the javascript for Google Analytics by using TYPO-Script (in Template):

```
page.headerData.124034 = TEXT
page.headerData.124034.value (

<!-- Google Analytics -->

<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push (['_setAccount', 'UA-##-my-ID-##']);
_gaq.push (['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
_gaq.push (['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>

<!-- Google Analytics End -->

)
```

TYPO3 renders on frontend:

```
 <!-- Google Analytics -->

 <!-- Google Analytics End -->
```

So the complete script-section is missing. My code worked on TYPO6 6.1.3 very well. I think it stopped working when i updated to TYPO3 Version 6.1.4 or 6.1.5.

Has anyone a idea how get it to work again?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the TEXT-Type do not accept script tags anymore.

Try to use:

```
page.includeFooterJS.c (
    <script type=”text/javascript”>
        alert(“Yes, scripts can also be added inline.”);
    </script>
)
```

Or:
http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/footer_js/0.0.1/view/1/3/

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is sth wrong with your template, e.g. some other template is  overriding this value. 
Have you checked if you see correct value in the Template object browser?

I have tested the exact code you have shared and it worked without an issue in TYPO3 v8.7